# Не запускается Vagrant со стандарными настройками в UBUNTU

Tags: php, ubuntu, oracle, vmware, vagrant

При попытке загрузить vagrant по инструкции http://www.olindata.com/blog/2014/07/installing-vagrant-and-virtual-box-ubuntu-1404-lts
 для работы с Laravel вылезает следующее сообщение:

> ```
> >      The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
> >     to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
> >     'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured
> >     properly and try again.
> >     
> >     If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
> >     it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
> >     GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
> >     For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
> >     VirtualBox GUI is open.
> ```

Я так подозреваю, что мне нужно сменить порт, или же как то дать ему доступы. Однако пока не понимаю как. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с ошибкой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сожалению у меня просто была выключена визуализация в BIOS. После включения виртуальная машина была запущена.